# Making a jar file run specific files first

Tags: java, executable-jar

I've made a jar file for all my classes and yes it works. Although it's not running my custom GUI. I'd like to set the jar file to run my GUI before anything else, and from there the rest of the files will be executed.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

When I run it through the command prompt using

```
java GUI
```

it works, but I need to do this using a jar file as I want my class files obfuscated.

Comment: A jar file can't with any sense be called an obfuscation method. Anyone with a passing interest in poking at your app knows it's just a ZIP archive.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood me... I want to be able to run a specific class using a jar file. Once I have that, I will be obfuscating the jar.

Comment: What's the issue? Set the main class in the manifest and execute whatever you want. I'm assuming you have a deobfuscating jar class loader.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Newton, solved.

Comment: You (the OP) are not describing your problem very well.  We get "it works" and "it's not running my custom GUI" and "like to ... run my GUI before anything else" and "rest of the files will be executed".  So you have multiple "files" to be "executed"?  Are they classes, C programs, what are you talking about?  You run it "through the command prompt"; in what state is your program and the "rest of the files" in the way it is "working" now?  Does "working" include the custom GUI that "it's" not running?   Assume we do not know anything about what you're doing, and describe it again.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you jave just .class files now and you want to create a .jar file.

To run a jar file you must add -jar after the java command.

Jar files are zip files which contain the classes, possibly resources and a manifest that tells which class has the main() method.

The jar command is used to create a jar file.

```
jar cvfm output.jar Manifest.txt *class package1 package2
```

and in **Manifest.txt** you should have this line:

```
Main-Class: MainClass
```

After that just run:

```
java -jar output.jar
```